# How to update firebase changes without reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, next.js

When the user changes his profile picture, it doesnt update until they reload the page...
Here is y code:

```
const handleProfile = async (e: any) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const storageRef = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`/profile/${user?.id}/${user?.username}`)
    const task = storageRef.put(file)
    task.on('state_changed', () => {
      storage()
        .ref(`/profile/${user?.id}/${user?.username}`)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => updateUser({ img: url }))
    })
  }
```

I tried with:

```
setTimeOut(() => {
location.reload}, 200)
```

but it doesnt works

Comment: Try `window.location.reload()` instead of `location.reload()`. But as @Doug Stevenson already wrote in the answer below, Firebase doesn't support realtime listeners. The best way to handle this would be to send another AJAX with GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the tags I'm assuming this app is using react, if so updating the state or the props in the profile picture component will cause react to re-render, which should show the new profile picture

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage for Firebase doesn't have realtime listeners like you find with Realtime Database and Firestore.  You can't simply arrange to receive callbacks for an object in storage when it changes.  It makes sense that you'd have to reload the page to fetch the object again.

You might consider instead using one of those realtime database products to **also** store updates to objects instead, and use a listener for that data to know when the object has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Stevenson suggested, you might wanna store the download URL of said object in Cloud Firestore and listen to its updates using the onSnapshot functionality.